# Embed Devise new session form in other controllers' pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My Rails 5.2, Devise 4.7 app has the standard single sign_in page  for new devise sessions.

I want the user to be able to browse a few different pages before signing in, and for each page to have the sign in form on it.

How can I display the devise form for new sessions in the views of other controller actions? Is there a way to run the code from the `Devise::SessionsController#new` action, from my other controllers? Or do I need to keep a single signin page for new sessions and then add custom things to the page via separate ajax actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put an empty `<div id="preview_here"</div>` in app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb and it gets populated from ajax calls (to non-Devise controllers with `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a three ways:

1. You can create custom popup with same form but change form to remote and also change your `form_for` accordingly.
2. You can add ajax processing to `Devise::SessionsController#new` action (add `respond_to` and create js template to render it) and then call this action on needed pages.
3. Move to React/Angular/Vue